# no picture with fswebcam

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, webcam, raspbian

A month ago, I test the following code to take picture with my webcam connected to a Raspberry pi (I used python3).

```
import os
import datetime
os.system ("fswebcam -d/dev/video0 -r640x480 /home/pi/Documents/%s.jpeg" %datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime (%Y-%m-%d- -%H-%M-%S"))
```

It works well and I had no problem but, since a week or so, it doesn't work anymore. The code returns no error message but, there is no picture in the 'Documents' folder. Everything seems to indicate that pictures are taken, but I cannot find them.

I looked for the pictures in the other folders but couldn't find them.
I updated the raspberry pi but it changed nothing.
I tried to run the script 'alone' with the command line

```
fswebcam -r 640x480 test.jpeg
```

The picture is taken and appears in the home/pi/ folder.

I tried to run the script as a super user but it opens the help menu of fswebcam. (???)

does one of you have an idea why it does not work anymore, what I did wrong and where are my pictures?

Comment: I tried to unplug then plug the webcam, but no changes.
I also uninstalled fswebcam and reinstalled it but no changes...

Comment: I have the similar problem, it is taking picture but it is blank. When I delete --crop from my line run and re-enter the line and run it works, seems like there is a bug when you run it first time.

Comment: Try implementing this in python that's what I'm looking at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

- Your script might be changed, you should check it or change to another folder.
- Because Raspberry Pi has no realtime, so you should consider this point if you set names of pictures according to the "date", so there might be the new pictures are saved in Documents folder but overwrite old pictures.